# The names of Gehinnom

Tags: names, talmud-bavli, maseches-eruvin, gehinnom

Babylonian Talmud, ‘Erubin 19a'
Joshua b. Levi said: The Gehenna/Gehinnom has seven names; Sheol, Abaddon, Beer Shahat, Tit ha-Yawen, Sha’are Mawet, Sha’are Zalmawet, and Gehenna.

What exactly is ment by Gehinnom (I know that its name was borrowed from that of a real valley mentioned in the Tenach, and I know what it serves for; a cleansing process) and what are its seven names refer to (just looking for the meanings since some of these names are used in verses like Mishlei 15:11 and I wonder if they have more meaning behind it)?

Comment: "what [do] its seven names refer to": presumably to it.

Comment: Try the Malbim - he tends to explain why things are called by different names.

Comment: I don't know much about it, but I have been to Gey (ben) Hinnom and it seems a nice enough place

Comment: Actually, in the times of Shlomo HaMelech, that particular valley was used for sacrifices to the Molech, IRCC.